# Deployment Error Visual Studio

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app, visual-studio-2017

I am following a tutorial around here: [SharePoint Add-Ins](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-started-creating-sharepoint-hosted-sharepoint-add-ins)

and of course before I get started following this tutorial I created a developer site, after I created the project and linked my developer site to the project.

while I am trying to compile I get these errors:

[image]

And

[image]

I have edited `NewEmployeeOrientationComponents.feature.xml` a new option which is **AlwaysForceInstall="TRUE"**.

But still doesn't work and remain the same error.

Is there any possible solution to fix this error?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is complaining about the content of the elements file. Please see [this page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/list-instances), which is the documentation for the listinstance xml element, which has an example of the content in this file. Note that the data element is inside of a ListInstance element, and is then inside of the Elements node. If this doesn't address your issue, please post the content of your elements file.

Comment: Thank you ! My mistake was that i put data element outside the listinstance xml element. @Mike2500